# How does 360 Security keep their notification up after reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, reboot

The 360 Security application shows notification with some settings through a permanent notificaiton. I would like to achieve the same thing, but after rebooting the notification dissapears and it takes quite some time to get it show up. The 360 Security on the other hand is up instantly after rebooting the device.

I've tried to add the [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) intent receiver and start my own notification from there, but I am unable to get it up fast enough (not even close). My notification appears 15-30 seconds after the 360 Security's notification.

This is how the 360 Security notification looks like (It can be disabled thrugh the notification settings):

[image: 360 Security Notification]

Am I missing something? Is there an option on how to create *permanent* notification which survives the reboot, or do they simply get the [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) intent faster? If so, why?

EDIT:
Other workaround might be setting the application as homescreen, but this does require user interaction and probably isn't the solution I'm looking for.

EDIT2:
I have also observed that if force close the application before rebooting, then its notification does not show up after the reboot.

Comment: Gotta assume that 360 Security spent a lot of time in the deeper realms of Android, likely took advantage of the NDK at some point.

Comment: Interesting, but how would NDK allow you to do something like this? I thought it allows you to access only the same API which is accessible in the Java, but within the native code (Meaning faster processing power).

Comment: I haven't utilized the NDK much, and am making a very bold assumption, they just have to be doing something that is allowing them more granular control.

Comment: Indeed, if you are inerested in the answer, could you upvote the question for more attention? Thanks for the comments though, I might look into the any APIs accessible within the NDK.

Comment: ForceClosing an app puts it in **Disabled** state, hence causing not to receive the broadcast until launch by the user - which puts it back into enabled state.